# How to create an array with reference member in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

I have some class Foo and Logger:

```
class Logger{/* something goes here */};
class Foo{
  Foo(Logger& logger);
  Logger& logger;
}

Foo::Foo(Logger& logger) : logger(logger)
{}
```

Now I want to create an array of objects of class Foo, where all references `Foo::logger` should point to the same `Logger` object. I tried something like (I need both stack and heap allocation):

```
Logger log (/* parameters */);
Foo objects [3] (log); // On stack
Foo* pObjects = new Foo [3] (log); // On heap
```

The problem is that both versions try to call the default constructor `Foo()` which is not present. Also as I understand it is not possible to change the referenced variable of a reference. So a temporary call to the default constructor and a later initalisation in a loop does also not help.

So: What is the right way to do it? Do I need to use pointers to the `Logger` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general uses I normally make a logger a Singleton so there is only one and can be accessed from all components. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

This also makes the constructor of Foo much simpler.

```
class Logger
{
    public:
        static Logger& getInstance()
        {
            static Logger    instance;
            return instance;
        }

        public log(const std::string& txt) 
        {
            //do something
        }

    private:
        Logger() {}
        Logger(Logger const&);              // Don't Implement.
        void operator=(Logger const&); // Don't implement
 };
```

And use it in Foo like:

```
 Logger::getInstance().log("test");
```

or

```
 Logger& logger = Logger::getInstance();
 logger.log("test");
```

(Credits for singleton from @Loki Astari : [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) )

Comment: To be sure that I understand you: You mean some static member for all objects? How to initialize it then? Or a separate object/global variable/...?

Comment: He means a singleton class which is accessible from everywhere in your code. This is the common way for loggers.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot initialize an array of objects with non-default constructor. 
However you can use a vector as shown [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/586377-array-objects-non-default-constructor-possible) (Look at the first reply)

And for the heap you can do the following :

```
Foo* pObjects[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
   pObjects[i] = new Foo(log);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize an array of objecs with the non-default constructor using the C++11 brace initialization:

```
class Logger{/* something goes here */};
class Foo{
public:
  Foo(Logger& logger);
private:
  Logger& logger;
};

Foo::Foo(Logger& logger) : logger(logger)
{}
```

---

*EDIT*: In C++11, you can use `vector` to do what you want:

```
#include <vector>
class Logger{/* something goes here */};
class Foo{
public:
  Foo(Logger& logger) : logger(logger) {}
private:
  Logger& logger;
};

int main () {
  Logger log;
  std::vector<Foo>(3, log);
}
```

Note that the `vector` solution won't work in C++03. In C++03 that vector constructor invokes `Foo::operator=`. In C++11 it invokes `Foo::Foo(const Foo&)`.

Comment: That only works if I know the number of elements a priori, right? This is not always true for my problem.

Comment: True, that is a problem. But realize that you must know the number of elements *a priori* when you create arrays on the stack.